# How do I undo a fold?

Tags: cursor-movement, folding

I noticed that when I fold some text with zf and then press u for undo it does not undo the fold but undoes the last text editing action. Is there a general-purpose undo command which also would undo the action of having created some fold? It should be as if the command did not happen, so I can imagine the cursor returning to the end of the highlighted range where it was, for example.

Comment: I really wish there was a solution for folding to be part of history too.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *undo* a fold, you open it with `zo` or delete it with `zd` (this doesn't delete content, only suppresses the notion that there's a fold there, closable with `zc`).

In general, try `:help`  followed by the keystroke you've tried to find out more. `:help zf` leads you to the topic of folds, and these other commands are documented there.

Comment: Thanks. I did know that I can undo a fold. I meant that the standard undo command, "u", appears not to apply to the act of folding. Maybe it applies only to editing commands. If folding counts as a motion, maybe there's an "undo last motion" command instead. If there was, you could call it from anywhere rather than having the cursor on the specific fold to undo it; and you could keep calling it to undo various consecutive previous actions, of which a fold was just one.

Comment: Indeed, undo is reverting a *change*. Folding, saving, pasting,... are not changes and are not in the undo tree - of which you can think of as a git tree of commits, see `:help 32.1` and following. A jump motion can be reverted by using the jump history (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>).